# Why <img> is not shown with the image, it shows image shortcut only

Tags: javascript

```
const img = $('<img>').attr('src', imgdir);
$('.response').last().append(img);
```

I see the shortcut only, I need to right click on that shortcut and select 'load image' then the image shown.

The shortcut of my image shown: [image: ()]

I've tried many times but it is not working as expected.

Comment: Are you sure the `src` you're passing is correct?

Comment: correct, beacause I right click on the shortcut and select Load image, or open image in new tab, i can see the image.

Comment: What is the value of `imgDir` and what format is the image?

Comment: What browser are you using? I've seen _"Open image in new tab"_ but where does this _"Load image"_ come from? Are you using any extensions that control image loading?

Comment: It's "../images/imgname.png", i'm sure the scr url is correct. It just not shown as an image instead of a small shortcut :(

Comment: I use Chrome, i can see the results, but it's only the small icon/shortcut. "load image' is a option when i right click on the img shortcut/icon

Comment: Are there any errors in your console? What about any failed requests in the dev-tools _Network_ panel? This isn't answerable without more debugging information

Comment: I see that if scr is from other website (https://otherweb.com/img.png), the img loaded. But if scr is my own website ("https://mywebsite.com/img.png" or "/img.png"), it isn't loaded. Anyone can help me? :(

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this error. My case is, i use js to download and save some img from other sources to my hosting, after that bring it to the screen. The img has not completely been upload to hosting, while the tag img has executed. Normally, it takes 5-10s delay for uploading.